# How to make pl/sql code to Ansi-Sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query, ansi-sql, connect-by

My question may be not challenging for sql expert. i want to rewrite my sql as a ansi-sql. How can i change below sql to ansi-sql in Oracle?

```
select * 
from TEST r
start with r.childid=@CHILDID 
connect by prior r.PARENTID=r.childid and r.recordstatus=1
```

Comment: `@CHILDID` is not a valid PL/SQL variable reference. Where and how are you running this statement?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Oracle RDBMS and not SQL Server.

Comment: i am using Oracle RDBMS

Comment: Do you want ANSI SQL as defined by ISO/ANSI, or are you migrating to a specific dbms, e.g. MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI SQL equivalent would be a recursive common table expression:

```
with recursive tree as (
   select * 
   from test
   where childid = .... --<< this is the START WITH part
   union all
   select child.* 
   from test child
     join tree parent ON child.parentid = parent.childid and child.recordstatus = 1  --<< this is the CONNECT BY part
) 
select *
from tree
```

I'm not 100% if you also want to apply the `recordstatus = 1` condition to the recursion start.

---

Oracle doesn't comply with the standard here, and you are not allowed to use the `recursive` keyword.

So you need to **remove** `recursive` from the query above (the same is true for SQL Server)

More details about recursive common table expressions (called "subquery factoring" in Oracle) can be found in the manual:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55268

Comment: Note: if the OP is moving to SQL Server (as possibly hinted by the `@` for parameters), then SQL Server doesn't support this syntax, but does support this idea, it merely requires the `recursive` keyword to be left out.

Comment: @hvd: Penguen specifically asked for ANSI SQL and the `recursive` keyword is required according to the standard.

Comment: I am aware of that, and I am not trying to say your answer is wrong for the question that the OP actually asked. However, I suspect the OP asked the wrong question.

Comment: it makes "missing keyword" error. drawing "tree" below. i guess something wrong in "with recursive tree"

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\PLSQL Developer\plsqldev.exe

Comment: "pl sql developer" i am using. Yes Oracle database.

Comment: @Penguen: well Oracle doesn't support the ANSI SQL syntax. You need to remove the `recursive` keyword.